# Connecting Laravel with facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

I am trying to connect with Facebook, and get the users name, email, and location.

I am having trouble understanding the permissions and scopes. the code I have only returns this

```
Array
(
    [name] => Ben Shepherd
    [id] => 123xxxxxxxxxx
)
```

And here is my code

```
public function facebookRedirect()
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => URL::route('takepart.facebook.callback'),
        'scope' => 'public_profile'
    );

    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
}

public function facebookCallback()
{
    $code = Input::get('code');
    if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

    $me = $facebook->api('/me');

    Helper::pr($me);
}
```

Comment: this may ease your pain http://laravel.com/docs/authentication#social-authentication

Comment: what if i'm using Laravel 4.2? there doesn't seem to be any social docs for that

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/

> Fewer default fields for faster performance: To help improve performance on mobile network connections, we've reduced the number of fields that the API returns by default. You should now use the ?fields=field1,field2 syntax to declare all the fields you want the API to return.

As such,

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
```

needs to be adjusted to fetch the specific profile fields you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've managed to get a bit further. I can get the id, name, email. All I need now is their country, but the fields 'address', 'hometown' or 'location' does not work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @BenShepherd Those fields require the extended permission `user_hometown` (and Facebook will have to review your app).